# Javascript Find string in a table like array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

This question have two parts: first, I want to create an array that works like a table. It will have two columns ids (`Game-Id` and `Game-Name`). I have been working in something like this:

```
var game_list = 
  [
    {id:1, name:'Vampires hunter'},
    {id:2, name:'Christmas vampires'},  
    {id:3, name:'Fruit hunter'},
    {id:4, name:'The fruitis'},
    {id:5, name:'james bond'},
    {id:6, name:'Vampires hunter'},
    {id:7, name:'Vampires avalon'},
    {id:8, name:'Vampires warrior'},
    {id:9, name:'Vampires hunter'}, 
    {id:10, name:'Vampires hunter'},
  ];
```

But I'm not able to access elements in this kind of array / object, not even a `document.write` of an element.

What I need is to create a function that will search for a specific string inside that array. The function will have 2 parameters (the string and the array) and it will give us a result an array of the elements with game names and ids that match that string.

Comment: Use Array.prototype.filter, with obj.name.indexOf(search) in your return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function filter(arr, string) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name === string;
  });
}

filter(game_list, 'Vampires avalon'); // [{ id=7, name="Vampires avalon"}]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YyfWJ/3/)

If you want to be *really* clever, add some regex to match the string anywhere in the name:

```
function filter(arr, string) {
  var regex = new RegExp('.*' + string + '.*');
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return regex.exec(el.name);
  });
}

filter(game_list, 'hunter');
```

Which will give you this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Vampires hunter"},{"id":3,"name":"Fruit hunter"},{"id":6,"name":"Vampires hunter"},{"id":9,"name":"Vampires hunter"},{"id":10,"name":"Vampires hunter"}]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YyfWJ/9/)

Comment: Nice, I like this better than mine!

Comment: thanks @Andy, it's not working with this:
var game_list = {
1: {name:'Vampires hunter', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},2: {name:'Christmas vampires', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},3: {name:'Fruit hunter', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},4: {name:'The fruitis', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
5: {name:'james bond', description:'The best vampires game in the world'}
};

Im getting this error: return arr.filter(function (el) {

Comment: [See here for more information on how to output stuff on the page.](http://jsfiddle.net/YyfWJ/23/). Try not to use `document.write`, it's considered bad practice.

Comment: @Andy sorry to bother you but i was trying to make it work with the structure (in the prevoius comment) which is a bidimensional associative array, it will be REALLY appreciated.

Comment: [I've updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyfWJ/27/). There's an extra function called `getData` that takes your new structure and changes it into one that the code will understand.

Comment: @Andy is there any chance i can contact you by email to explain this better ? i have to use just plain js for this and i dont understand why you making the getData function.

Comment: I can't do that, I'm afraid. Let me try and explain it to you. `filter` is an `Array.prototype` method. It won't work on an object, only an array. So to keep my answer and get your data into a structure that it will accept I had to loop through the object and extract the contents into an array, exactly like in your question.

Comment: Totally understand @Andy, Is there any way to make it work with the same structure but not using filter and with just plain javascript ?

Comment: Sure, but you should post another question if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop and check will do:

```
function checkArray(name) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < game_list.length; i++) {
        if (game_list[i].name == name)
            arr.push(game_list[i])
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Will compare the `name` passed in with the `name` of each object, and returns an array of matching objects. If you only want names containing the passed in string, use `indexOf` and check on `-1`